# Word Mail Merge using C# From Access Database

Tags: c#, templates, ms-word, mailmerge

Hello and thanks for the help:

I have a program written in visual basic that takes a Word Template, a passed SQL string and a save location. It then opens the template file using the SQL string to only get one record linked back to an access database and saves the file as a PDF.

This runs succesfully.... I need to convert it to C# which I have a little knowledge of as we are moving the Save location to SharePoint and want to be able to program the SharePoint Metadata once the file has been created.

I can't find any examples of doing this in VB hence the change to C# as most seem to say you need to iterate through the merge fields one at a time which is not possible - there are hundreds and we embed logic in the document using If Then Else in the merge fields. My first step is to get the current software functional in C#.

VB.NET Software below:

```vb
    Private Sub MergeandSaveActual(ByVal strDocument As String, ByVal strQuery As String, ByVal strSaved As String)
        Try
            Dim intCounter As Integer = 0

            If strSaved.Substring(strSaved.Length - 4) = ".PDF" Or strSaved.Substring(strSaved.Length - 4) = ".pdf" Then
                strSaved = Left(strSaved, (Len(strSaved) - 4))
            End If

            Dim objWord As New Object
            objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") ' Creating a word application

            Dim objDoc As New Object
            objDoc = CreateObject("Word.Document") ' Creating a word document object

            objWord.application.WindowState = 0 ' set the word window in normal state (Const wdWindowStateNormal = 0)
            objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(strDocument) ' Add the mail merged document file

            Dim NameBeforeWordMerge As String = objWord.ActiveDocument.Name

            objWord.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource("c:\ Link to access database",
            Connection:="dsn=DSN NAME; dbq=" & "c:\ Link to access database" & ";",
            sqlstatement:=strQuery)
            With objWord.ActiveDocument.MailMerge
                .MailAsAttachment = False
                .MailAddressFieldName = ""
                .MailSubject = ""
                .SuppressBlankLines = True
                With .DataSource
                    .FirstRecord = 1  ' Const wdDefaultFirstRecord = 1
                    .LastRecord = -16 ' Const wdDefaultLastRecord = -16 (&HFFFFFFF0)
                End With
                .Execute(pause:=True)
            End With
            Dim NameAfterWordMerge As String = objWord.ActiveDocument.Name
            objWord.Documents(NameBeforeWordMerge).Close(0) ' close the template doc
            objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(strSaved & ".pdf", Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)
            objWord.Documents(NameAfterWordMerge).Close(0) ' activate the mail merged doc after record population
            objWord = Nothing
            ' Pause until the document is avaliable
            intCounter = 0
            While intCounter < 6
                If System.IO.File.Exists(strSaved & ".pdf") = True Then
                    intCounter = 10
                Else
                    intCounter = intCounter + 1
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                End If
            End While
        Catch excep As System.Exception
            LogFile.TextFileWrite("Word Merge " & excep.Message)
            strErrorBox = "Word Merge " & strErrorBox & excep.Message
            ProcessingForm.ErrorLogTextBox.Text = strErrorBox
            Kill_Processess.KillProcess()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

In C# I get the document to open but how do I pass along the SQL query?

Code which opens the document:

```
 private static void MergeandSaveActual(string strDocument, string strQuery, string strSaved)
    {
        try
        {
            int intCounter = 0;
          
            if (strSaved.Substring(strSaved.Length - 4) == ".PDF" | strSaved.Substring(strSaved.Length - 4) == ".pdf")
            {
                strSaved = Strings.Left(strSaved, Strings.Len(strSaved) - 4);
            }
           
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object readOnly = false;
            object isVisible = false;
            object fileName = strDocument;
            object fileNameSaveAs = strSaved;
            object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatRTF;
            object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;

            Application oWord = new Application();
            Document oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(fileName);
            oWord.Visible = true;
            Interaction.MsgBox("Here");

            
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {
            LogFile.TextFileWrite("Word Merge " + excep.Message);
            GlobalVars.strErrorBox = "Word Merge " + GlobalVars.strErrorBox + excep.Message;
            My.MyProject.Forms.ProcessingForm.ErrorLogTextBox.Text = GlobalVars.strErrorBox;
            Kill_Processess.KillProcess();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for looking and any assitance.

Answer (score 0):

So, solved this to a point. The below code works but will only merge fields if they have an IF statement in them. As most of my documents have siginificant IF checks within them it was easier to put a check for a blank value in the document and then Merge the field than try to figure out how to check for non IF statements within the document.

strDocument = the merge template location and file name.
strQuery = SQL query to get one record set for the merge document to use. However this must follow string SQL language properties. E.G SELECT * FROM [Table A] WHERE [Column] = something
strSaved = the name of the created document and location to save too.

```
private static void MergeandSaveActual(string strDocument, string strQuery, string strSaved)
    {
        try
        {
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object oFalse = false;
            object oTrue = true;
            object oSql = strQuery;
            object fileName = strDocument;
            object fileNameSaveAs = strSaved;
            object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;
            object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
            object paramMissing = Type.Missing;
          
            Application wordApplication = new Application();
            
            Document document = wordApplication.Documents.Add(fileName); // Add Was Open
            document.Activate();
            document.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(@"LINK TO DATABASE", oMissing, oFalse, oTrue, oTrue, oFalse, oMissing, oMissing, oTrue, oMissing, oMissing, @"dsn=DSN NAME; dbq=LINK TO ACCESS DATABASE;", oSql, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

            
            document.MailMerge.MailAsAttachment = false;
            document.MailMerge.MailAddressFieldName = "";
            document.MailMerge.MailSubject = "";
            document.MailMerge.SuppressBlankLines = true;
            document.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = 1;
            document.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = -16;
            document.MailMerge.Execute(true);
            document.Activate();
            wordApplication.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(ref fileNameSaveAs, ref fileFormat,
                ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing);
            
            object doNotSaveChanges = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;

            wordApplication.ActiveDocument.Close(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            wordApplication.Quit(doNotSaveChanges); //This is used to quit the Word application.
            GC.Collect(); //This is used for Garbage collection.    
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {
            LogFile.TextFileWrite("Word Merge " + excep.Message);
            GlobalVars.strErrorBox = "Word Merge " + GlobalVars.strErrorBox + excep.Message;
            My.MyProject.Forms.ProcessingForm.ErrorLogTextBox.Text = GlobalVars.strErrorBox;
            Kill_Processess.KillProcess();
        }
    }
```